# Call to make pair with mutex as argument fails. Cannot insert mutex onto unordered map

Tags: c++, unordered-map, stdtuple

Below is an error

```
std::mutex mtx;
            auto t = std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), mtx);
```

But the following is not?

```
std::mutex mtx;
            auto t = std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), 1);
```

My ultimate goal is to create a create an unordered map of type:

`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::mutex>`

Using:

`mHeartBeatMutexes.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), mtx));`

But my IDE is saying it's wrong and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Is it allowed to copy construct mutices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::mutex` is not copyable or moveable.  When you do

```
std::mutex mtx;
auto t = std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), mtx);
```

and

```
mHeartBeatMutexes.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), mtx));
```

`std::make_pair` tries to make a copy of `mtx` since it is an lvalue and it can't because `std::mutex` is not copyable.

In

```
std::mutex mtx;
auto t = std::make_pair(std::string("hello"), 1);
```

`1` is an integer literal which materializes into a temporary integer that is moved (copy really as it's the same thing) and that's all good.

To put a mutex into a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::mutex>` what you need to do is use the emplace function to directly create the pair inside the `unordered_map` leverage the [`std::piecewise_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct) overload and [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) to build the arguments for each member of the pair's constructor like

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::mutex> foo;
foo.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple("hello"),
            std::forward_as_tuple());
```